# How can I change the hosts file in windows docker container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, azure-iot-edge

In our solution we want to connect our Edge module to the servicebus of a host on a different network.

The dns server is not allowed (per design) to have the dns mapping to that host, hence I need to do the dns mapping in the hosts file of the Windows container that the Edge module is running in.

I have done some tests with the docker run and docker build commands, setting the --add-host parameter, but this doesn't seem to be supported in Windows containers. Looking at the file after the container has been started with that flag at least suggests that it is not.

Moreover I'm not sure I can use this since the Edge runtime is in control of the running of containers (please correct me if I'm wrong here).

In my desperation I tried to modify the hosts file through code, but got stopped due to administrative previledges not beeing met.
Anyways this feels like a hack and is not what one should have to do.

Is there an easier way to add a dns host mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a windows base image - you could modify the hosts file there.

Comment: Thank you. I am not addressing the other host through dns, but with its ip address so I'm not sure that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with cmd, like this

```
docker exec --user "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -it <container> cmd
```

and when I got that shell I've run:

```
echo x.y.z.w hostname >> c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

at first i've tried with powershell but all I got was some weird blank spaces between my text